# How can I add content at the beginning and at the end of a file in Notepad++?

Tags: python, notepad++

I need to find a regular expression or a PythonScript function to add text before the first character of the first line and after the last character of the last line. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you downrate my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

Find what: `(.+)`
Replace with: `DEBUT$1FIN`

Make sure that `Regular Expression` is checked and `Dot matches newline` also.
Then clic on <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

Comment: This adds text to every line. I need to add text at the beginning of the document and at the end of the document.

Comment: @xephon: No, it doesn't if you check `Dot matches newline`.

Answer (score 0):

This works in [PythonScript](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net):

```
// Add the text "foo" before the first character
editor.insertText(0, "foo")
// Add the text "bar" after the last character
editor.insertText(editor.getLength(), "bar")
```